# How to load table dynamically on the checkbox value in gsp

Tags: grails, checkbox, gsp

I am working on a table in gsp which i want to load dynamically on a checkbox value.. I need if the checkbox is unchecked than the table will show the following fields

```
Name  age country status
Tom   35  USA     Confirm
Nick  30  USA     ready
Alex  25  Canada  Inprogress
Johny 20  UK      Waiting
```

and if the checkbox is checked it will show all the fields

```
Name  age country status
Tom   35  USA     Confirm
Nick  30  USA     ready
Alex  25  Canada  Inprogress
Johny 20  UK      Waiting
Dipu  22  USA
Jack  22  UK
```

I am using the following code

```
   <g:each in="${domainInstanceList}" status="i" var="domainInstance">
                <%

                     //color = "#ff4d4d"
                     color = "#FF6868"
                   def  name = domainInstance?.name
                   def  age= domainInstance?.age
                    def country= domainInstance?.country

                    if (domainInstance.isConfirm) {
                        //color = "#b3ccff"
                        color = "#56B9CC"
                        status = "Confirmed"
                    }
                    if(domainInstance.isReady){
                           status = "Ready"
                    }else if(domainInstance.inProgress ){
                        status = "Inprogress"
                    }else if(domainInstance.iswaiting  ){
                        status = "Waiting"
                    }


                %>

                <tr style="background-color:${color}" class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                        <td><b><g:link action="show" id="${domainInstance?.id}">${domainInstance?.prefix}${domainInstance?.number}</g:link></td></b></td>

                        <td>${name}
                        <td>${age}
                        <td>${country}
                        <td>${status}

                </tr>               
            </g:each>
```

can i use jquery in it ... how ?
Please help me
thanks

Comment: use jquery eg. add a class ('nostatus') to the tr if there is no status and add an event listener to the check box to hide 'nostatus' class

Comment: why don't you use status as the actual status  rather than all these boolean. alternate to above the check box does a jquery get to form and this time strips the ones not needed from results - but tbh - that all looks so messy - you could iterate through `domainInstanceList` in controller and append required values. Looking at that personally I don't think it needs any additional input - additional common sense or better ways - https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/e35e382ce17c931e4ef08ac356102ca5ad1e590b/grails-app/domain/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/Email.groovy#L36

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/e35e382ce17c931e4ef08ac356102ca5ad1e590b/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugin/queuemail/enums/MessageStatus.groovy follow it through here and here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/e35e382ce17c931e4ef08ac356102ca5ad1e590b/grails-app/views/queueMail/_list.gsp#L115 and actual english translation https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuemail-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties#L127-L135 - now you have been shown better ways no excuse

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery answer here, but simplify perhaps... no need for name, age, country local vars. If you're massaging domain instances to get a representation, I prefer doing the work in the controller, and leaving the gsp as simple as possible, such as creating a personStatuses list of maps of [id, linkText, name, age, country, status, color] for each domain instance, and passing that to the gsp.

```
<g:each in="${personStatuses}" status="i" var="ps">
  <tr style="background-color:${ps.status}" class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
    <td>
      <b><g:link action="show" id="${ps.id}">${ps.linkText}</g:link></b>
    </td>
    <td>${ps.name}</td>
    <td>${ps.age}</td>
    <td>${ps.country}</td>
    <td>${ps.status}
  </tr>               
</g:each>
```